# In Maven how to run a JUnit test case as part of a test suite and not alone?

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, junit, junit4

I have 3 JUnit test cases that run as part of a test suite. The Test suite starts and stops an embedded Rabbit MQ server used by these test classes.

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
    TestQueueGateway.class, 
    TestRabbitMQConnectionFactory.class, 
    TestRabbitMQQueue.class
})
public class RabbitMQIntegrationTestSuite {
@BeforeClass
public static void setupRabbitMQServer() {
    //Start embedded server
}

@AfterClass
public static void _tearDownAfterClass() {
    //stop server
}
}
```

I can run this test suite in Eclipse and see that the test cases are correct. However when I run a Maven build, the 3 test classes are running independently and fail, because they do not have the needed server setup.

Please let me know how I can make the 3 test classes run only as part of the test suite and do not run independently during Maven build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use maven-surefire-plugin to include your testsuite,

```
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/RabbitMQIntegrationTestSuite.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```